# Datetime format postback invalid ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, modelstate, displayformat

I'm having an issue using the DisplayFormat attribute on a Datetime property during the postback validation.

To be clear this is not a main issue but I would like to understand a way to make it works without a 'hack' or simply discuss about this point (in the case that's a 'normal' behavior).

Let's admit that I have some datetimes in DB (eg. 10/17/2014 12:00:00 AM) to display in a form. I'm using the `DataType(Datatype.Date)` and `DisplayFormat(...)` attributes but when I post back my form I got the ModelState to be invalid due to Datetime format.

### *--MyModel class file (.cs)*

```
namespace Package.To.Models {
    public class MyModel 
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true]
        public Datetime myDate { get; set; }

        ...other properties
    }
}
```

### *--cshtml file*

```
  @model Package.To.Models.MyModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.myDate) 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <!-- displayed with the good format eg. 17/10/2014 -->
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.myDate)
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Ok" class="button"/>
    </fieldset>
}
```

### *--controller file (.cs)*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult calledWhenSubmit(MyModel model)
{
  // invalid model.myDate: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

  var errors = ModelState
               .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
               .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
               .ToArray();
  // errors.Errors[0].ErrorMessage: "The value '17/10/2014' is not valid for myDate"
  // errors.Errors[0].Exception._COMPlusExceptionCode: -532462766

  if (ModelState.IsValid) // returning false
  {
    ...some code
  }
  return View();
}
```

It appears that if I delete the `DisplayFormat(...)` attribute everything works fine (except the fact that the displayed date is in the wrong format in the form).

I found a lot of posts about Datetime and ModelState issues on SO but nothing in a config as simply as I got so I'm all ears about what I'm missing

Comment: Did you set a culture in your `web.config` file (ie `<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />`) ?

Comment: Have you set the culture to en-Gb in the config?

Comment: nope, I didn't set the culture anywhere

Comment: Try that and let us know if it works please

Comment: it doesn't change anything, same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Although you set the `DateFormatString` but the controller validation does not understand this format, it understands the culture format. You need to change it in `Startup.cs` ConfigureServices method by adding the following code:

```
 var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
 CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```